# Actionscript3 difference between singleton and static

Tags: actionscript-3, singleton

In AS3 I have seen alot of people creating singleton classes using internal class n getInstance.

I would like to know whats the basic difference in singleton and keeping all public functions/vars static???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Singleton in AS3

- Can implement **interface**. (power of polymorphism)
- You can **inherit** from it or **extend** it from other class.
- Can be passed as a **parameter** to other method.
- **Its methods can be passed** as a parameters to other methods. (**Almost unique**)
- **Lazy** instantiation support *
- **One** instance, `this` keyword *

### Static in AS3

- Simple to reach
- No instance, no `this` keyword *

---

*Updated/added due meaningful comments

Comment: Also, a Singleton also benefit from lazy instantiation, while static vars don't.

Comment: +1 for a good try however you are missing something important. With a Singleton you only ever have exactly one instance of the class where with static there is no instance. With static there is no "this".

Answer (score 1):

The main difference is that singletons can extend other classes and implement interfaces, and generally be passed around like a 'normal' object instance.

Answer (score 1):

Singleton is used when you need to keep some data in the manager class, And usually static doesn't, like Math functions